# HTML5 custom validation not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

i've the following function to verify matching between 2 password input fields.
When i submit the form even if the password match i got the error and i don't understand where is the problem.
Can you guys have a look?
thanks

```
function checkPwdMatch() {

if (document.getElementById('password').value !=document.getElementById('confirm_password').value) {
document.getElementById('confirm_password').setCustomValidity('Two Passwords must match.');
} else {
document.getElementById('confirm_password').setCustomValidity('');
}

}
```

----FORM FIELDS----

```
<input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" value="" required>

<input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="<?php echo $lang["joinRepeatPassword"]?>" value="" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password"  required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are not other elements with the same id (password or confirm_password) in your html code?

---

When I have such html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>


function checkPwdMatch() {

if (document.getElementById('password').value !=document.getElementById('confirm_password').value) {
document.getElementById('confirm_password').setCustomValidity('Two Passwords must match.');
} else {
document.getElementById('confirm_password').setCustomValidity('');
}

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" value="" required>

<input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="password copy" value="" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password"  onblur="checkPwdMatch()"  required>


<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

if I put aaa and bbb in two inputs, it shows they are invalid and when i put aaa and aaa everything seems to be ok. If the problem is after you send form and page refresh you need to send more details I think.

Comment: yes i've doublechecked and i confirm you that no other fields with the same id are present on the page.

Comment: I think you should show a bit more code - the form and how you launch checkPwdMatch function

Comment: i launch the function directly from the field with onblur event
<input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="<?php echo $lang["joinRepeatPassword"]?>" value="" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password"  onblur="checkPwdMatch()" required>